# How to tag the Term with the highest percentage of the class in R

Tags: r

```
y       app          baby           blackberry          dear   
Neg      20          33.33           100                100       
Neutral  80          66.66            0                  0     
Pos      0            0               0                  0
```

In the above data frame,"app" is having more percentage for class Neutral. So I have to combine the "app" term with Neutral sentiment. Likewise,term "blackberry" has more percentage for class "Negative".So have to combine the term "blackberry" with class 'Neg'.

Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear about the expected output.  If we need to find the corresponding 'y' term for the maximum value in other columns, use `summarise_each` with `which.max` to get the numeric index and based on that we can get the 'y' value for those columns form 'app' to 'dear'

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df1 %>%
         summarise_each(funs(y[which.max(.)]), app:dear)
res
#       app    baby blackberry dear
# 1 Neutral Neutral        Neg  Neg
```

This can be converted to 'long' format with `gather` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
res %>%
    gather()
#        key   value
#1        app Neutral
#2       baby Neutral
#3 blackberry     Neg
#4       dear     Neg
```

---

Or we can `melt` it to 'long' format (from `data.table`) and use `which.max`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "y")[, .(value = y[which.max(value)]),.(key= variable)]
#          key   value
#1:        app Neutral
#2:       baby Neutral
#3: blackberry     Neg
#4:       dear     Neg
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$y[sapply(df1[-1], which.max)]
#[1] "Neutral" "Neutral" "Neg"     "Neg"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(y = c("Neg", "Neutral", "Pos"), app = c(20L, 80L, 
0L), baby = c(33.33, 66.66, 0), blackberry = c(100L, 0L, 0L), 
dear = c(100L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("y", "app", "baby", "blackberry", 
"dear"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: res <- df1 %>%                                                                                         
         summarise_each(funs(y[which.max(.)]), app:dear)
res                                                                                                                             But in above code,the first term and last term will not be fixed.It can be any term

Comment: @Payal Okay, it was based on the example showed.  If you have a 'y' column at least, then  `df1 %>% summarise_each(funs(y[which.max(.)]), -y)`

Comment: Yes..but the first term and last term will not be fixed..It can be any term

Comment: @Payal In that case, use the index `df1 %>% summarise_each(funs(y[which.max(.)]), -1)`  Also, the 'y' part denotes the column where the terms are.

Comment: Done! Thanks..By the way I am doing my research work in R but as R is new for me..Its to difficult for me to complete It I am done with 80% of project..can I get your help if possible

Comment: @Payal Sure, post your questions in stackoverflow and somebody would be always available to help you.

Comment: @Akrun..I have one more question on "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681546/i-have-to-pass-the-data-frame-to-ctree-for-classification"..can you please look into it?