# I have to pass the data frame to Ctree for classification

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
y       app          baby           blackberry          dear   
Neg      20          33.33           100                100       
Neutral  80          66.66            0                  0     
Pos      0            0               0                  0
```

I have to pass this dataframe to Ctree function  for sentiment classification

Can anybody please help me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the package which has this `Ctree` function?

Comment: This works :  BOW_ctree_tf_3g_95 <- ctree(y ~ ., data = sum_list).

Comment: But in the confusion matrix,it is considering every document as negative :(